# Processing Query Strings?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony-2.2, fosrestbundle, symfony-2.3

Built an API using Symfony2, FOSRest and Doctrine. Given the following route:

```
"GET /api/path/to/product"
```

And the following parameters:

```
[("vendorID", 10), ("destination", "tanzania"), ("type", "accommodation"), ("sort", "price", "ASC")]
```

Using FOSRest bundle its possible to retrieve these strings, however, mapping them to doctrine queries is where the challenge arises.

I thought about using numerous case statements customised for the different combinations of query strings, not an elegant solution. Would like to build a more generic controller that won't severely affect performance. Any advice will help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The FOSRestBundle has a very cool [param fetcher listener](http://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSRestBundle/3-listener-support.html#param-fetcher-listener). With it you can define your query string parameters with annotations, allow them nullable or not, set default values, define requirements. Based on your example parameters I guessed some values

```
/**
 * @QueryParam(name="vendorID", requirements="\d+", strict=true, description="vendor id")
 * @QueryParam(name="destination", nullable=true, description="restrict search to given destination")
 * @QueryParam(name="type", nullable=true, description="restrict search to given type")
 * @QueryParam(name="sort", requirements="(price|foo|bar)", default="price", description="sort search according to price, foo or bar")
 * @QueryParam(name="dir", requirements="(ASC|DESC)", default="ASC", description="sort search ascending or descending")
 */
 public function getProducts(ParamFetcher $paramFetcher)
 {
     $vendorID = $paramFetcher->get('vendorID');
     // and so on
 }
```

For building the query builder, it's very simple with the params which have a default value, as they will never get filled with an undefined value. For strict params it is also no problem, as a strict param will raise a `400 Bad Request` if it's missing or does not fit the requirements. Only with nullable params you have to check against not null before you add the conditions to the query builder.

Btw. take a look on the [NelmioApiDocBundle](https://github.com/nelmio/NelmioApiDocBundle), which generates for every action annotated with `@ApiDoc` a nice documentation. It parses also the param fetcher annotations. Very handy.

Comment: Thats well and good problem comes with instantiating the query or should that be delegated to the product repository class?

Comment: Edited my answer that moment. You can pass them all to the repository function, and only on the nullable params you have to check against a not null value before adding conditions to the query builder.

Comment: Thanks a lot Pazi. Will implement and let you know. Thanks again

Comment: I believe you meant `400 Bad Request`?